# Bootstrap changing navigation bar colour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Which parameter of the `bootstrap.css` file i should edit to change the **colour of the nav bar**.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  ...
</nav>
```

`navbar-inverse` gives black colour, but i want white. i went through `bootstrap.css` and changed all attribute color that belongs to `navbar-inverse` to `#fff` but nothing worked.

Any clue?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's inspector? That will tell you where the style is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the navbar requires overriding multiple selectors. Below is most of what you'll need:

```
/* This of course assumes you're using .navbar-inverse */

/* Navbar main background */

.navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: white;
}

/* Navbar title */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: lightgray;
}

/* Focus/hover state for navbar title */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: black;
}

/* Navbar links default color */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: orange;
}

/* Navbar links hover/focus states */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: pink;
}

/* Active link colors */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
}


/* Mobile toggle button */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: lightgreen;
}

/* Mobile toggle button hover/focus states */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #DDD;
}

/* Mobile icon bar colors */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/McHUc/6/

Comment: How do i change the outline colour and selected menu button colour (from black to some other colour) ?

Comment: @Illep: The outline colour would be controlled with using `border` on the first selector, `.navbar.navbar-inverse` and what do you mean *"selected menu button colour"* - I don't understand.

Comment: In your example you will see a black outline around the nav bar. i need to change color of it. and the `Home` button is set to `active` and it is gray. Which attribute is responsible for this.

Comment: For the active link the selector is: `.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus` and the black outline is controlled by using `border` on `.navbar.navbar-inverse`

Comment: I still don't understand how to add a colour when the menu is in `active`. Can you guide me ?